# UIImageView Created In Interface Builder Set To nil When Needed

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an application where small number of objects are defined in the MainWindow.  A pair of these objects are a UIViewController and the UIImageView that goes along with this controller.  When the application starts up, the entire MainWindow.xib get loaded & I can see that this UIImageView has been loaded into memory.  At this point, I have no need for this UIImageView.

When I need the UIViewController, I perform the usual alloc/init setup.  At this point, when I look at this controller with the debugger, the controller is setup correctly, but the UIImageView that should have been pre-wired with Interface Builder is always nil.

Any suggegstions on how to make sure this UIImageView is loaded into memory correctly?  This is the only case where I've had an issue with objects defined within this single MainWindow.xib file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have connected the `view` outlet, all you need to do is access the `view` property. When you look in the debugger, you're seeing the property's corresponding ivar. When you access the property in code, it should load for you. So, it should be as simple as:

```
  [controller view];
```

Comment: I tried the [controller view], but from what I see, it didn't work.  I have this definition in my header file: `@interface FlickrViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *photoView;
    NSString *photoURL;
}` I attempt to setup "photoView" via Interface Builder.  I believe I have the IB connections correct.  But, whenever I attempt use or look at "photoView," I find it is always set to nil, which is incorrect.  Unfortunately, I don't have a good understanding of what is going on to fix it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand the problem, but instead of having the UIImageView in MainWindow.xib, why not have it in the xxxViewController.xib where it's actually going to be needed?

Comment: I tried splitting the xib files this morning.  If I create a separate xxxViewController.xib file, I get the same UIImageView set to nil.  Unfortunately, I don't have a good enough understanding to give you a better explaination.